# Why does LINQ do joins differently from SQL?

Tags: c#, linq

In LINQ I can do a join like this:

```
from c in dc.Customers
join o in dc.Orders on c.custid equals o.custid ...
```

However left joins are far more complicated:

```
from c in dc.Customers 
join o in dc.Orders on c.custid equals o.custid 
into temp from x in temp.DefaultIfEmpty() ...
```

Why couldn't the designers of LINQ make things simple (more SQL-like) with something like this?

```
from c in dc.Customers
left join o in dc.Orders on c.custid equals o.custid ...
```

Answer (score 5):

> why couldn't the designers of Linq make things simple (more sql like)

They could have.  But your definition of simple (as a sql programmer) is not the same as the OO programmer's definition of simple.  Linq (in C#) is a query technology for OO programmers, first.  An example of this is *why select comes last*.  That's to fulfill scope rules in C# and intellisense support in the editor.

These programmers maybe don't get `LEFT JOIN` (and get really confused if you say `LEFT OUTER JOIN` - thinking there's some difference, like one inherits from the other).

What they do understand is `GROUP JOIN`, which behaves in a similar manner.

```
List<int> myInts = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
List<int> myOtherInts = new List<int>() { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13 };
//
var query = from i in myInts
    join j in myOtherInts on i equals j into g
    select new {key = i, myGroup = g};
//
foreach (var grouping in query)
{
  Console.WriteLine("--{0}", grouping.key);
  foreach (var x in grouping.myGroup)
    Console.WriteLine(x);
}
```

All that `DefaultIfEmpty` stuff does is unpack the group - flattening the results into **row/column form** - away from the OO programmer's **natural heirarchical form**.  `DefaultIfEmpty` is not semantically necessary to get to the results.

Here's the same query in method form - which the compiler generates from the above and which I prefer:

```
var query = myInts.GroupJoin(
    myOtherInts,
    i => i,
    j => j,
    (i, g) => new { key = i, myGroup = g }
);
```

---

> Could you state that in terms of his example?

This query gives you customers, with their orders as an attached collection.  The orders collection might be empty.  If you have 50 customers and 1000 orders, you will have 50 customers in the result.

```
from c in dc.Customers
join o in dc.Orders on c.custid equals o.custid into someOrders
select new CustomerWithOrders()
  {theCustomer = c, theOrders = someOrders};
```

This query gives you a CustomerOrder row.  If a customer has 5 orders, the customer will appear 5 times, each time matched to a different order.  If the customer has 0 orders, the customer will appear once matched to a null order. If you have 50 customers and 1000 orders, you will have 50-1049 rows after the join and the meaning of an element in the result is hard to define.

```
from c in dc.Customers
join o in dc.Orders on c.custid equals o.custid into temp
from x in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new CustomerOrderHybrid() {theCustomer = c, theOrder = x}
```

If they implemented `left join`, it would require the result shape of the second example.  Once I used the `group join`, which is better, I wouldn't implement the `left join` in one step either.  Hierarchical shaping of query results is great.

Comment: I don't see how your answer addresses the question. Could you state that in terms of his example?

Comment: I'd first life to say thanks for taking the time to wrote your your thought provoking post. I'll have a closer look tomorrow - my immediate response however is to say that there is a clear Sqlish slant to Linq already so to say that OO programmers wouldn't get it doesn't really wash as a reason.

Comment: Ouch my brain hurts... but I think I understand about the LINQ designers trying to preserve heirachical representations in preference to flattened ones.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because Linq expressions are simply [syntactic sugar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) in the compiler, which translates them into method calls. So the query syntax is a leaky abstraction of an object-oriented system.

Since you're not actually writing SQL, there are bound to be cases where the underlying technology behaves differently. Adding a SQL-like 'left join' is probably a lot harder than you think.

---

Some people evidently don't know how Linq expressions work, so here's a further explanation.

If I take this test class:

```
public class Class1
{
    public List<string> list = new List<string>() { "test", "test1", "test2" };

    public void test_lambda()
    {
        var test = list.Where(l => l == "test1");
    }

    public void test_linq()
    {
        var test = from l in list
                   where l == "test2"
                   select l;
    }
}
```

`list.Where(l => l == "test2")` is compiled to the same code as `from l in list where l == "test2" select l`. In both cases the compiler generates anonymous method delegates:

```
.method public hidebysig instance void test_lambda() cil managed
{
    .maxstack 8
    L_0000: ldarg.0 
    L_0001: ldfld class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1<string> Class1::list
    L_0006: ldsfld class [System.Core]System.Func`2<string, bool> Class1::CS$<>9__CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate1
    L_000b: brtrue.s L_001e
    L_000d: ldnull 
    L_000e: ldftn bool Class1::<test_lambda>b__0(string)
    L_0014: newobj instance void [System.Core]System.Func`2<string, bool>::.ctor(object, native int)
    L_0019: stsfld class [System.Core]System.Func`2<string, bool> Class1::CS$<>9__CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate1
    L_001e: ldsfld class [System.Core]System.Func`2<string, bool> Class1::CS$<>9__CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate1
    L_0023: call class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<!!0> [System.Core]System.Linq.Enumerable::Where<string>(class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<!!0>, class [System.Core]System.Func`2<!!0, bool>)
    L_0028: pop 
    L_0029: ret 
}

.method public hidebysig instance void test_linq() cil managed
{
    .maxstack 8
    L_0000: ldarg.0 
    L_0001: ldfld class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1<string> Class1::list
    L_0006: ldsfld class [System.Core]System.Func`2<string, bool> Class1::CS$<>9__CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate3
    L_000b: brtrue.s L_001e
    L_000d: ldnull 
    L_000e: ldftn bool Class1::<test_linq>b__2(string)
    L_0014: newobj instance void [System.Core]System.Func`2<string, bool>::.ctor(object, native int)
    L_0019: stsfld class [System.Core]System.Func`2<string, bool> Class1::CS$<>9__CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate3
    L_001e: ldsfld class [System.Core]System.Func`2<string, bool> Class1::CS$<>9__CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate3
    L_0023: call class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<!!0> [System.Core]System.Linq.Enumerable::Where<string>(class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<!!0>, class [System.Core]System.Func`2<!!0, bool>)
    L_0028: pop 
    L_0029: ret 
}
```

This is what I mean by syntactic sugar. Query expressions don't add anything new to the language, they just provide an easier way of using existing language features.

Comment: Linq is not syntactic sugar.  the compiler doesn't translate anything INTO lambda expressions.  No one said anything about generating SQL in the question. -1

Comment: OK, I'm not positive it's lambdas per se, but linq IS syntactic sugar, and gets translated into method calls by the compiler.

Comment: Linq is more than query expressions.  I'll withdraw my -1.

Comment: I think there was confusion due to my original use of 'linq' without qualification. I've clarified that, since linq refers to many, many different things.

Comment: The question is about Linq to SQL, that is a query of type IQueryable<T> instead of IEnumerable<T> as in your example. In Linq to SQL, the compiler will not translate to method calls, but instead generates an expression tree that a library can translate to anything it chooses (like SQL strings).

Comment: To be more precise, the choose for generating either plain method calls or an expression tree, is based on the type of the expression. That is, whether the type is `Func<T, R>` or `Expression<Func<T, R>>`.

Comment: It just so happens to be that `IEnumerable<T>` implements methods with a `Func<T, R>` type and `IQueryable<T>` methods with type `Expression<Func<T, R>>`.

Comment: Were I querying a DataContext in my example, both expressions would have been compiled into Expression Trees instead. My point was that Query Expressions are syntactic sugar that is converted into more traditional objects behind the scenes. I am aware that it is more complicated than I let on.